# Installing plaincart on hostgator

Tags: mysql, php, database

OK, so I am following  [this tutorial](http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/) and I'm trying to deploy the sample code onto my MySQL and PHP web server over at Hostgator.

OK, so I have all of the files contained in a folder called `plaincart` (the folder I downloaded from the site I mentioned above).

Now, in the `README` file, it says the following about installing this on a webserver:

```
INSTALLATION INSTRUCTIONS

1.) Unzip plaincart.zip to the root folder under your 
    HTTP directory ( or under your preferred directory) 

2.) Create a database and database user on your web
    server for Plaincart

3.) Use the sql dump in plaincart.sql to generate the
    tables and example data

4.) Modify the database connection settings in 
    library/config.php.

5.) If you want to accept paypal modify the settings
    in include/paypal/paypal.inc.php . More information
    about this paypal stuff can be found in 
    http://www.phpwebcommerce.com/shop-checkout-process/
```

OK, so how **EXACTLY** do I go about doing these steps?  From #2 onwards.  Obviously I know how to unzip the file, and I can just dump it into my web server, correct?
2)  How to I create a database on my server?
3)  I'm assuming this is referring to filling the newly created database (from step #2) with sample data contained in a file from the `plaincart` folder?  I have that file, and have verified that it contains some sample data.
4)  How do I know what to modify this *to?*

5)  We'll see about this when we get there.

Any info on *any* of this is greatly appreciated, as I'm trying to help someone out with this ASAP! :)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Obviously I know how to unzip the file, and I can just dump it into my web server, correct?

   yes, you can unzip it on your computer and upload it.
2. [AFAIK hostgator uses cPanel so your first step would be login to your cPanel account and go to MySQL database and create it using the wizard available there.](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-database-a-user-and-then-delete-if-needed)
3. [Once you do the above you can use the phpMyAdmin available within cPanel and feed your database with the plaincart.sql there is a import option.](http://www.hostgator.com/tutorials/xskincpanel/cpanel_xskin_phpmyadmin.htm)
4. using your preferable editor on your computer edit the file library/config.php with the data it requests then upload to the server

   for example, in the file you will have to set the user, pass and database name you have created on step 2:

   ```
   // database connection config
   $dbHost = 'localhost';
   $dbUser = 'root';
   $dbPass = '';
   $dbName = 'phpwebco_shop';
   ```

   [Additional information on connecting to mysql](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/how-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database)
5. Can't help you with this one since i dont have the file but i am sure you got the idea from the above steps that you will need to open the configuration file for paypal that comes with the file and is on that given folder and change the needed options on it.

Comment: you welcome :) !